# tamil font is not working in tcpdf pdf generation

Tags: php, tcpdf

We are developing tamil text pdf generation using TCPDF. Im using

```
$pdf->SetFont('freeserif', '', 10);
```

[image: sample]

Answer (score 0):

**Did you add your font ?**

```
$font = $this->addTTFfont("tamil_FONT.ttf");
```

Another alternative

```
tcpdf/tools/tcpdf_addfont.php -i /path/to/fonts/tamil_FONT.ttf
```

Comment: i tried this already its not working

Comment: @Palani Did you set header and pdf as UTF8,   header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', utf8_encode($CONTENT_), 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);
$pdf->Output('tamil.pdf', 'I');